# Contact Form Validation using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-validate, validation

I Want to validate a for with jquery form validation. So i include the following coads.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2  /jquery.min.js"></script> 
  <script type="text/javascript" src=" http://jzaefferer.github.com/jquery-validation/jquery.validate.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
               $(function() {                           
                             $('#contact-form').validate({
                                 rules:{
                                   name:{
                                     required:true
                                   },
                                   email:{
                                     required:true,
                                     email:true
                                   }                                                                     
                                 }
                             });
                           });
  </script>
```

But when i am clicking the submit button then an error is shown like

> TypeError: $("#contact-form").validate is not a function

Help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a weird space breaking up your jQuery script include url. You're probably getting console errors about the script not loading if you'd look.

```
/1.7.2  /
```

Needs to be

```
/1.7.2/
```

Answer (score 1):

it works here http://jsfiddle.net/UWhJE/

make sure the jquery is loaded before you include the validate.js. Also check for javascript errors in the firebug console (for firefox) or in chrome development tools

Answer (score 0):

Make sure jquery and jquery.validate load successfully. You can call the function as above but usual way is to call it document.ready. Hope it helps.